# Tumblr RSS feed set max results?

Tags: rss, feed, tumblr

Does anyone know a way to do this.. I searched their API and came up blank http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/developers

I was using blogger before and was able to set the results like this `blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=1000`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer straight from Tumblr's tech support (**it's no**)

> Tess, Sep-22 09:54 (EDT):
>
> I'm sorry, but that isn't supported at this time. My apologies.
>
> Tess
>   -- Tumblr Support support@tumblr.com
>
> Sam Saccone, Sep-21 21:14 (EDT):
>
> hello, I requested an rss feed only to find that it was limited at 20
>   results
>
> is there a way to get all the results?